# Unable to mount SMB share using Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, snow-leopard, unix, smb

I have a Linux box (Raspberry Pi) with Samba set up, and when I try to mount the shares on a MacBook Pro (Snow Leopard, 10.6.8) it just stalls. I have an Applescript that runs at login, which I use to mount them, and the `mount volume` action never terminates.

Similarly, when I run `mount_smbfs` or `mount -vt smbfs`, the command provides no output whatsoever, and continues to run (C-c gives me a prompt, but doesn't terminate).

Using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in Finder or smb/cifs URI schemes just provides the "Connecting To Server" dialog, which disappears instantly, or never closes at all.

The only log message that shows up is the typical firewall message (this has always happened) in appfirewall.log.

> Deny nmblookup data in from 10.0.1.42:137 to port 56874 proto=17

`smbutil -v lookup -w 10.0.1.42 <hostname>` gives the expected output.

A reboot fixes the issue, but I still don't know what is causing it.

Comment: can you post the code from your Applescript where you issue the mount commands?

Comment: @Annjawn It's not important, just how I found the problem. Basically it just uses ping to find out if the server is connected, then does `mount volume "smb://10.0.1.42/pi-web-server"`

Comment: I don't understand - first you say that you want to mount at login and that fails, then you say that a reboot fixes it - that suggests that you reboot and it works, i.e. at login. Please elaborate.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann I log out/in after every session (to clean things up in optimism that it will prevent things like this, and because I share the computer with other people). And even if I did stay logged in, I still power off the Pi (it's just a testing server for Apache at this point), so I would have to mount the share multiple times anyway. I don't always want things on, but when I do it's automatic; that's what the script is for. Honestly the applescript is irrelevant, I just wanted to provide some background. The point is that _nothing_ is working (from this server) as SMB.

Comment: So, to clarify, logging in to the Pi works exactly once until you get logged out of the Pi - and then you have to reboot the Mac to be able to log in again?

Comment: BTW, which Pi system are you running? Got a Pi here, too, maybe I can reproduce it. What did you have to do to enable the SMB server on it?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann It's intermittent, and I can't say why there would be an issue. Sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes it doesn't, but a reboot always seems to reset it. The Pi is just standard Raspbian with apache2 and samba installed via APT.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13713/discussion-between-thomas-tempelmann-and-0942v8653)